# responsivefilemanager9 internal server error

Tags: php, tinymce, responsive-filemanager

I installed responsive filemanager 9 from [here](https://www.responsivefilemanager.com/index.php#documentation-section) into my local tinymce 4.

My tinymce config looks like this:

```
<script>
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  theme: 'modern',
  plugins: 'print preview fullpage searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help',
  toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat | responsivefilemanager',
  image_advtab: true,
  language: 'de',

  external_filemanager_path:"http://XXXX/info/upload/filemanager/",
  filemanager_title:"BSW Infoterminal Dateimanager" ,
  external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "http://XXXX/info/upload/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},

  templates: [
    { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
    { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
  ],
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]  
 });
 </script>
```

I can upload images over responsivefilemanager9, but i always get a Error `Internal Server Error` in frontend from RFM9. In the overview from uploaded files is no file shown.

In logs i see the following errors:

```
[14-Sep-2018 12:31:59 Europe/Rome] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mime_content_type() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\upload\filemanager\include\php_image_magician.php:2723
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\upload\filemanager\include\php_image_magician.php(230): imageLib->openImage('../source/ich.j...')
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\upload\filemanager\include\utils.php(403): imageLib->__construct('../source/ich.j...')
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\upload\filemanager\UploadHandler.php(1436): create_img('../source/ich.j...', '../thumbs/ich.j...', 122, 91)
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\upload\filemanager\UploadHandler.php(1387): UploadHandler->onUploadEnd(Array)
#4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\upload\filemanager\UploadHandler.php(187): UploadHandler->post(false)
#5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\upload\filemanager\UploadHandler.php(171): UploadHandler->initialize()
#6 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\upload\filemanager\upload.php(167): UploadHandler->__construct(Array, true, Array)
#7 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\upload\filemanager\include\php_image_magician.php on line 2723
```

[image: Upload Error]

[image: Directory Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just don't have php extension **fileinfo** installed.
You can enable it by adding the following string to your **php.ini**

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

and restart your web server.

Here you can find some more details about the installation process:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php